# Querying JSON Array in Laravel Eloquent with a Condition on Price

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm working on a Laravel project where I have a JSON array stored in a meta field, and I'm trying to retrieve records based on a condition on the price within the JSON array. I have a key-value pair, where the value is a JSON array that looks like this:

```
[{"id":1,"product_id":1,"title":"Blue","price":"42.99",...}, 

{"id":2,"product_id":2,"title":"Black","price":"22.99",...}]
```

I want to fetch records where the price in the JSON array is less than a given value.

Here's my current Eloquent query:

```php
$query->whereHas('metaFields', function ($meta) use ($value) {
    $meta->where('key', 'variants')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($value) {
            $query->whereRaw("JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(value, '$[*].price')) < ?", [$value]);
        });
});
```

The above query gives incorrect result

Comment: It looks like an error occurred in the relation table, I tried a similar scenario and didn't get the error. here is the code I tested `$orders = Order::query()->whereHas('orderDetails', function ($query) use ($value) {
             $query->whereNotNull('created_at')
                 ->where(function ($subQuery) use ($value) {
                     $subQuery->whereRaw("JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(product_cycle_payload, '$[*].price')) < ?", [$value]);
                 });
         })->with('orderDetails')->get();`